# Load keras weights until a specific layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a 3dCNN model. I would like to load my stored weights in Keras until a specific layer. I have named the specific layer as name = "my_dense_layer". How can I load the weights until that layer?

My model looks like:

[image]

I would like to load my weights by skipping the last drop out and Dense layer that has size 6. Then, I would like to project my input of size `32x10x28x28` and using the weight of the specific Dense layer that has output size a vector of 512 dimensions. Thus to have as an output `32x512`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the stored weights are arranged as `b1, w1, b2, w2 ...`, we can load the weights layer by layer until to `my_dense_layer`. A possible solution as followed:

```
for layer in model.layers:
if layer.trainable_weights:
    b=weights.pop(0)
    w=weights.pop(0)
    layer.set_weights((b,w))
    if layer.name=='my_dense_layer':
        break
```

Comment: My model is fully trained until the end. I just want to load part of it until the specific Dense layer. As far as I understand your solution add extra layers to the pre-trained model, right?

Comment: But what exactly weight represent in that case?

Comment: The weights are your pre-trained stored weights. Keras model store its weights as a list of numpy array, which contains `b` and `w` of every layer with trainable parameters.

Comment: It seems to me that .pop(0) twice just do the work without the if statements.